# Matplotlib. Pyplot does not work with pycharm

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

I downloaded matplotlib 3.2.1 for pycharm. And when i try writing `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` and running the program, it does not work and give me this error:

[image: this error]

what can i do to make matplotlib work??
thanks in advance.

Comment: you could start with showcode and not post screen shots of tracebacks. Also how are you managing your enviroment? are you using virual envs? ifso how are you installing modules?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't've named your file `matplotlib.py`. Look what happens when you do this:

```
$ echo "print('importing myself'); import matplotlib" > matplotlib.py
$ python3 matplotlib.py
importing myself
importing myself
$
```

See - `importing myself` is printed *twice*! When `import matplotlib` is executed, Python attempts to load `matplotlib.py` itself, *not* the `matplotlib` module!

Thanks to caching, `import`ing `matplotlib` from within a file called `matplotlib.py` doesn't cause any recursion errors.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of your py . It cannot be `matplotlib.py` because python loads it from your folder and not from it's libs.

Comment: Also pycharm has nothing to do with your python code not working. It's just an GUI.